# taking a row of pictures from 4 in a row to 3 to 2 to 1 responsively

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, rows

Im trying to get rows of pictures with text below to be responsive as the screens width gets smaller. Trying to go from 3 rows of 4, to 4 rows of 3, to 6 rows of 2, to one single row.

Is this the right css and what is the responsive element that needs to be added?

```
<li class="body-members">
<div class="bios">
    <div class="module" alt="The League">
        <div class="picture-holder">
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>  
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>  
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>  
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>  
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>  
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>      
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <img src="#"/><ol><li>Name</li><li>Row2 text</li><li>row3 text</li></ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.picture {
height: 320px;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
width: 25%;
display: block;
vertical-align: center;
}
.bios {
width: 100%;}
.module {
width: 75%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;}



 .picture-holder {
width: 100%;
display: block;}

.picture img {
display: block;
border-radius: 50%;
border-color: white;
border-width: 5px;
margin: 0 auto;}

.picture ol {
padding-top: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish that is to use the 'float' property. Put each image and its associated caption in a div. Use the CSS rule 'float: left' on each of those divs. As the screen width gets smaller, the divs will rearrange themselves so that they don't overlap.

If you want to control how many images are in each row, use media queries to set the size of your main div based on the width of the screen. E.g. `@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 720px)`.

You should read up on `float` and `@media` usage, as there's a lot to the topic.